# Rails paperclip can't load images on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm having some trouble to load images with paperclip on my production server.

I can save the image on database, and if i check on default path where it is created, the image is there but when i try to load it on page i get error 404.

- I use phusion passenger on production server
- I have tested on cloud9 workspace on development and it works fine

[image]

[image]

Comment: We need more information, its probably the url being generated differently on production, but thats were i would start.
Comparte the url generated in development and the one in production, vs the expected.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)